# Does data remain in HDFS when Hadoop cluster is down?

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Qubole and wanted to know if data remains in HDFS after Hadoop cluster is down?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I read about external tables in Hadoop. Eventhough we drop external table the data remains. Is this applicable for data when hadoop cluster is down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what is down in the cluster. There are daemons in Hadoop, Namenode, data node, Resource manager, AppMaster and etc.

So if Namenode is down (Master node), then the data remains as is in the cluster, BUT you will not be able to access it at all. Because, Name node holds the meta data of the data nodes.

If a Data node is down on a cluster (slave node), then you will not be able to access the data from this node, but by default data will be stored in 3 locations in the cluster for fault tolerance. So you can still access the data from other two nodes.

Answer (score 2):

No data on HDFS is gone. We don't backup/restore HDFS. The model of computation on EC2/S3 is that the long-lived data always lives on S3 and HDFS is used only for intermediate and control data. We also use HDFS (and local disk), sometimes, as a cache.